# Cannot Upgrade from 10.04 due to "Karmic" error during upgrade

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10 and up. I am currently connected to the Internet. The last thing that I want to have to do is a fresh install since I dual boot the machine and I don't want to risk anything. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

I have been getting the following error:

```
Could not download all repository indexes

The repository may no longer be available or could not be contacted because of network problems. If available an older version of the failed index will be used. Otherwise the repository will be ignored. Check your network connection and ensure the repository address in the preferences is correct.

Failed to fetch <http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz [and sources.gz]>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch <see above>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch <see above>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch <see above>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch <see above>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch <see above>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch <see above>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch <see above>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### karmic vs lucid

Your error:

`Failed to fetch <http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz [and sources.gz]>  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]`

This is preventing your package management system correctly updating.  Karmic repositories no longer exist in the main launchpad repository area.

To resolve this first error you could use similar instructions as I described here:

- [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

i.e.

Comment out the offending karmic repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list` - that is, add `#` character to the start of the line to comment out the offending repository

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

[image]

Then ensure your package management system is OK:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Once you've confirmed this, you can then do a LTS to LTS upgrade - we've already got a great Q&A that describes this:

- [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

Comment: I would like to thank both of you for your input. With your suggestions, I have successfully managed to upgrade to 12.04. I sincerely appreciate your efforts. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would recommend a full backup and fresh install.  A lot has changed between 10.04 and 12.04 or 12.10 so a fresh install would be cleaner.

However since you don't want to do this.  The problem is that 10.10 is not supported any more so you can it can not find the 10.10 files.

To fix this you need to upgrade to the next LTS version which is 12.04.  To do this open "Update Manager" and click the "Settings Button".  In the window that opens change "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" to "For long-term support versions" instead of  "For any new version".

You may need to reboot for this to take effect, but I'm not sure.

You can now upgrade directly to 12.04.

12.04 "Precise" is supported until April 2017 so I would stick with that but If you want to you can upgrade from there to 12.10.

**Updates can go wrong so make sure you have good backups of both Windows and Ubuntu before updating**